# Google Tag Manager - track user with no activity

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am trying to create a trigger that will run after 20 seconds of no user activiry on page.
It works simply in theory but I couldnt find any solution of how to do that.
By no activity i mean no click ( gtm.click ) happening in that time.

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to create a [Timer](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679323?hl=en) trigger. You'll specify a name for the event that's used when it elapses (defaults to "gtm.timer", the interval at which it fires (in milliseconds) and an optional limit to cap how many times it fires (leaving it blank means it won't ever stop firing each interval).

You're describing a scenario where it should fire a single time at 20 seconds, so you'd want to configure it as in the following:

[image: Timer Trigger Example]

Comment: Hi! This part I am familiar with but problem is to add additional condition which is track if within this 20 second period client clicked on any place on the page.
For example : 
1) Client spent 20 second on page and clicked - trigger will fire
2) Client spent 20 second on page and didnt click - trigger wont fire